# python - frequency of power spectrum

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot a power spectrum from my data set (array of about 2000 values, the data is recorded every minute).

I've gotten so far as:

```
y= np.fft.fft(data)
abs = np.abs(y) #absolute value
p = np.square(abs) #power
```

but am confused about setting the frequency.

I've tried using `freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y))`, but when I plot the result it looks like, which can't be right.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to plot the power spectrum:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,2000,200)
data = 2 * np.sin(2*np.pi *60*t) + 2 * np.sin(2*np.pi *42*t)

spectrum = np.fft.fft(data)
power_spectrum = np.square(np.abs(spectrum))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(len(power_spectrum)), power_spectrum)
plt.show()
```

[image]